# Split a PPT-Shape-Picture into items

Tags: c#, powerpoint, system.drawing

How do I split a grouped picture of a PPT-shape into single items with C#; similar to the ungroup-function of PowerPoint. If you do it in PowerPoint, you can split e.g. a ClipArt Picture into its single elements, but how do I do this using C# code?

Where can I find the reference to the shape-picture. Can I use DrawingGroup in anyway here?

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in method on the PowerPoint shape object

> shape.Ungroup()

Is that what you want?